# Mysql Sub queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries im trying to run together. I can seem to get it to work . each query work by them selfs .but once i try to add them together with a sub query i cant seem to get to work

```
SELECT T1,100 * SUM(IF(C1='UNKNOWN', 0, 1)) / COUNT(C1) as 'MATCHING' FROM t1.CSLog WHERE CSHOUSE LIKE 'N%' group by CSHOUSE


SELECT T1,100 * SUM(IF(C1='UNKNOWN', 1, 0)) / COUNT(C1) as 'NOTMATCHING' FROM t1.CSLog WHERE CSHOUSE LIKE 'N%' group by CSHOUSE
```

the output should look like this

```
t1 | MATCHING  | NOTMATCHING

2  | 100%      |    0.0%
3  | 0.0       |   100%
```

Comment: The output without the input again :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this select?

```
SELECT 
  T1,
  100 * SUM(IF(C1='UNKNOWN', 0, 1)) / COUNT(C1) as 'MATCHING',
  100 * SUM(IF(C1='UNKNOWN', 1, 0)) / COUNT(C1) as 'NOTMATCHING'
FROM t1.CSLog 
WHERE CSHOUSE LIKE 'N%' 
group by CSHOUSE
```